# Prove the vector norm equation

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, proof-explanation

Show that the Euclidean norm of a vector v is given by a formula similar to that for
the matrix norm:
$||v|| = \max\{(x \cdot v)/||x||: x\neq0\}$
,
or equivalently
$||v|| = \max\{x\cdot v: ||x||=1\}$
by showing that the max on the left side is both $\leq$ and $\geq$ the norm $||v||$ on the right.

I'm not sure as to what it means by asking to show that the max on the left side is both $\leq$ and $\geq$ the norm $||v||$ on the right. Suggestions?

Comment: what does it mean ||v|| = max x:||x||=1 x · v ?, is it $\vert\vert v \vert\vert = \max \{ x : \vert\vert x \vert\vert = 1 \cdot \langle x,v \rangle \}$?

Comment: I think I've understood your notation, the first maximum is taken over $x \neq 0$, and the second one over the unit vectors, right?

Comment: yes thats correct. Heres a link to the question: #15 a) http://www.math.ubc.ca/~hajeong/problems_1.1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The proof follows from the Cauchy Schwarz inequality:

$$ \vert \langle x,v \rangle \vert \leq \vert\vert x \vert\vert \cdot \vert\vert v \vert\vert \quad \forall x,v$$
If you fix $x$, then $\forall v$ you have
$$ \frac{\langle x,v \rangle}{\vert\vert v \vert\vert} \leq \frac{\vert \langle x,v \rangle \vert}{\vert\vert v \vert\vert} \leq \vert\vert x \vert\vert $$

The bound $\vert\vert x \vert\vert$ is attained because if you take $v = x$ then

$$ \frac{\langle x,x \rangle}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert} = \frac{\vert\vert x \vert\vert^{2}}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert} = \vert\vert x \vert\vert $$

So it can be concluded that

$$ \vert\vert x \vert\vert = \max_{v \neq 0} \left\{ \frac{\langle x,v \rangle}{\vert\vert v \vert\vert} \right\}. $$

Comment: Sorry, in the proof I interchanged the roles of $x$ and $v$, but the proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To show the right hand side is $\leq ||v||$, use the formula $x\cdot v=||x||||v||\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $v$. Note that $\cos\theta\leq 1$ and $\cos\theta=1$ implies that $\theta=0$.

To show the right hand side is $\geq ||v||$, note that 
$$\max\{(x\cdot v)/||x||:x\neq0\}\geq (v\cdot v)/||v||.$$